# Query to get max Id from each Kind

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to get max X.Id from each Specific kind, Example:

Table:

```
Id | Kind
---------
1  |  20
2  |  20
3  |  15
4  |  15
---------
```

My query needs to get the Ids 2 and 4, because my kinds are 15 and 20, this is my current query:

```
SELECT max(Id)
   FROM X
WHERE KIND = 15 or KIND = 20
```

But this query only returns id 4. I need 2 and 4, the max Id for each kind.
I don't want to run more than one query. 
With subqueries and more than one query I know how to do.

I would like to know how to do with only one query.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT max(Id) as ID
   FROM X
WHERE KIND = 15 or KIND = 20
GROUP BY KIND
```

The result will be:

```
ID 
-----
2
4
```

**Suggestion**

You can use `IN` for simplicity:

```
SELECT max(Id) as ID
   FROM X
WHERE KIND IN (15,20)
GROUP BY KIND
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`group by kind`**

**[Group by Clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)**

```
SELECT max(Id)
FROM X
WHERE KIND = 15 or KIND = 20
group by Kind
order by 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4eaa/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Create table Test (Id int, Kind int)
Insert Test(Id,Kind) Values (1, 20)
Insert Test(Id,Kind) Values (2, 20)
Insert Test(Id,Kind) Values (3, 15)
Insert Test(Id,Kind) Values (4, 15)
Insert Test(Id,Kind) Values (5, 10)
Insert Test(Id,Kind) Values (6, 10)

Select * from Test

Select MAX(Id) from Test
Where Kind in (20, 15)
Group by Kind

Select MAX(Id) from Test
Group by Kind
Having Kind in (20, 15)

Drop Table Test
```

Comment: where are the filter by kind 15 and 20?

Comment: You should be using HAVING in combination with Group By if it is to be a calculated parameter, or simply add the where condition if it is about regular columns. Adjusted the code

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(Id), KIND
   FROM X
Group by KIND
```

Comment: Replace KING with KIND